# Maven only tries downloading from one repository

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have two repositories configured in the `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```xml
                        <repositories>
                                <repository>
                                        <snapshots>
                                                <enabled>false</enabled>
                                        </snapshots>
                                        <id>thirdparty</id>
                                        <name>thirdparty</name>
                                        <url>https://artifact.example.net/artifactory/thirdparty</url>
                                </repository>
                                <repository>
                                        <snapshots>
                                                <enabled>false</enabled>
                                        </snapshots>
                                        <id>our-releases</id>
                                        <name>our-releases</name>
                                        <url>https://artifact.example.net/artifactory/our-releases</url>
                                </repository>
                        </repositories>
```

The project's `pom.xml` makes no mention of either of the two. When I run `mvn install`, Maven tries to download the JARs from only one of the repositories.

When such a download fails (such as with 403 forbidden), Maven fails too -- instead of trying to obtain the same JAR from the other repository, which actually has it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please recheck the docs https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#repositories ?

Comment: I [read that document](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#repositories) before posting this question. I don't see anything there about the order, in which repositories are tried, nor about when Maven may not try additional ones.

Comment: But not defined only one of them as releases..enabled... Also I recommend to use a repository manager like Nexus or alike to handle such things...in particular in an corporate environment...

Comment: The releases and snapshots are identically en/disabled in the two repositories listed. Yet, only one repository is visited. artifact.example.net _is_ a "Nexus or alike" repository manager, actually -- not that it is relevant to the question...